# local issuer certificate for outlook addin

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, yeoman, outlook-web-addins

facing below issue

---

Unable to download project zip file for "https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Angular/archive/yo-office.zip".
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

I'm all done. Running npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.

Installed yo & generator-office using below commands
--- npm install -g yo generator-office

After successful installation, ran below command to generate the outlookin workspace
--- yo office

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is required for running web add-ins, so you need to create and install any self-signed certificate to run old solutions.

Also after installing the yeoman generator you can create a new add-in with a task pane. If you try to run such solution for the first time you will be asked to install a newly created self-signed certificate to run the add-in. Here is what MS states:

> Office Add-ins should use HTTPS, not HTTP, even when you are developing. If you are prompted to install a certificate after you run one of the following commands, accept the prompt to install the certificate that the Yeoman generator provides. You may also have to run your command prompt or terminal as an administrator for the changes to be made.

See [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) for more information.